# Serious problems with tabularx table layout

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have some issues when creating my tables in LaTeX and really hope, that some of you could help me. My table looks like this:

[image]

Here is my coding:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc} 
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.8\linewidth}{l !{\qquad} r X r X r X r}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Name1} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Name2} 
    \\ \cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{6-8}
              & Factor1 && Factor2 && Factor1 && Factor2\\
    \midrule
    Test 1 & 12 && 32 && 3 && 5 \\
    Test 2 & 1234 && 234 && 334 && --- \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

If it is possible, I would like my table to look like this (there should, of course, still be a space in the line below Name 1 and Name 2):
[image]

Further questions:

1. How do I add "Note:"?
2. How do I add table name?

Hope someone can help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: your code doesn't compile for several reasons however you are not saying it doesn't so I am not entirely sure what your problem actually is. for information, with the code provided: you are trying to use `tabularx` but are loading the `tabu` package; you are using `toprule`/`(c)midrule`/`bottomrule` without loading the `booktabs` package.

Comment: I forgot some of my preamble. Is it a problem, when loading both tabu and tabularx?

Comment: @A.F. No, not exactly a problem, they should be able to work next to each other. It was just strange that you didn't load `tabularx` and you use it.

Comment: Yes. That is right. I just forgot to c/p it. Do you have an idea to my problem? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend not widening a tabular beyond its natural width. With `tabular*` you can avoid “phantom columns”, if you really want to enlarge the intercolumn spaces.

With facilities from `siunitx` it's easy to make tables containing numeric data.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\begin{document}

% natural width
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{What is this table about?}\label{test1}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Name1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Name2} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
& {Factor1} & {Factor2} & {Factor1} & {Factor2} & {Total} \\
\midrule
Test 1 &   12 &  32 &   3 & 5     & 99 \\
Test 2 & 1234 & 234 & 334 & {---} & 99 \\ 
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l@{}}{\strut\footnotesize Note: Blah blah}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

% enlarged width
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{What is this table about?}\label{test2}

\medskip

\begin{tabular*}{.8\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Name1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Name2} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
& {Factor1} & {Factor2} & {Factor1} & {Factor2} & {Total} \\
\midrule
Test 1 &   12 &  32 &   3 & 5     & 99 \\
Test 2 & 1234 & 234 & 334 & {---} & 99 \\ 
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}l@{}}{\strut\footnotesize Note: Blah blah}
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For longer notes that need to be split across lines, the best is to load the `threeparttable` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,threeparttable}

% customize threeparttable
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteLabel}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

% natural width
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{What is this table about?}\label{test1}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Name1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Name2} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
& {Factor1} & {Factor2} & {Factor1} & {Factor2} & {Total} \\
\midrule
Test 1 &   12 &  32 &   3 & 5     & 99 \\
Test 2 & 1234 & 234 & 334 & {---} & 99 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[Note:] A long note that goes beyond the table width
  because we want to have many many words that
  mean as little as possible
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

% enlarged width
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{What is this table about?}\label{test2}

\medskip

\begin{tabular*}{.8\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=4.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Name1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Name2} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
& {Factor1} & {Factor2} & {Factor1} & {Factor2} & {Total} \\
\midrule
Test 1 &   12 &  32 &   3 & 5     & 99 \\
Test 2 & 1234 & 234 & 334 & {---} & 99 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[Note:] A long note that goes beyond the table width
  because we want to have many many words that
  mean as little as possible
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Egreg how do I add more space between lines, as you can see on my example?

Comment: @A.F. You might make `\arraystretch` larger, but my opinion is that larger spaces between rows don't improve the table.

Comment: Hi Egreg. I have a problem, when I write a long line in Notes, it would not break in two, so it continue outside the paper. How can I fix that?

Comment: @A.F. Do you know the `threeparttable` package?

Comment: No, I do not know that package. Should I add this in my preamble or?

Comment: @A.F. I'll add how to do it.

Comment: Hi egreg. Thank you, but what have you added above? I can't see it?

Comment: I have added the use package, but nothing happened?

Comment: @A.F. I have added the package, but also changed the code for the table.

Comment: Which things have you changed. The two preamble look identical?

Comment: I can't see "A long note that goes beyond the table [...]" anywhere else than in the attached pictures.

Comment: @A.F. Well, you're right! I copied the same example as above. Sorry. Fixed now.